# Duplicate checking in table withe select query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, duplicates

Below query is duplicate checking based on  `FirstName, LastName, PhoneNo` it not working for me because State column I didn't include in the grouping. So I want to include in return result in these fields also (`Emp_Id, PostCode, and State`) along with this result, duplicate checking only 3 this column (FirstName, LastName, PhoneNo). Can you help me?

```
select Distinct FirstName, LastName,PhoneNo from TestEmployee;
```

[image]

Comment: Use `MIN`/`MAX` and `GROUP BY` instead?

Comment: Sorry., I have updated my question...please walk through this...

Answer (score 1):

Expecting this?

```
 SELECT DISTINCT MIN(emp_id) AS emp_id, FirstName, LastName, max(postcode) AS postcode, [State],PhoneNo FROM Employees
 GROUP BY FirstName, LastName,[State],PhoneNo
```

Comment: I have updated Question please check this